# PaaS compatibility for WFFM and EXM?

Tags: wffm, exm, azure, paas

Are the current versions of WFFM and/or EXM supported on Azure PaaS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they are both compatible.

WFFM since 8.2 Update-3 (rev. 170413), and EXM since 3.5 (rev. 170810)

More information about all modules compatible with Azure Paas can be found here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/201557

Answer (score 3):

WFFM and EXM are now compatible with new Sitecore Versions.

EXM: since version 3.5 https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Email%20Experience%20Manager/35/Email%20Experience%20Manager%2035%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes

WFFM: since Sitecore Azure Tookit 1.1  https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Azure%20Toolkit/1x/Sitecore%20Azure%20Toolkit%20110/Release%20Notes

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

WFFM since 8.2 Update-3 (rev. 170413), and EXM since 3.5 (rev. 170810)

Source: [Sitecore XP on Microsoft Azure Compatibility Table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/201557)